# Extend integration by parts to triple product

Tags: integration

Do we really have the following formula for the triple product:
$\int u' vw = uvw - \int uv'w - \int uvw'$? I know how to derive it. Is there any restriction on the functions $u,v$, and $w$? Any source or confirmation would be appreciated.

Comment: You know how to derive it? can't you answer the question then?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm whether is it really true or not since I couldn't find any source (maybe it is too easy to derive).

Comment: Yes, its true, and yes, its not hard to derive; classical integration by parts followed by product rule. Or follow the derivation of the normal integration by parts-
$$ \int (u'vw + uv'w + uvw') = \int (uvw)' = uvw + C$$